# Scope seems to behave differently on Databricks compared to Visual Studio (for a same Python code)

Tags: python, databricks

Here is my issue:

I have an exact same code (copy-pasted) that I'm running locally on Visual Studio Code and also on Databricks. For some reason it works on Visual Studio Code but not on Databricks. Here is the error I get on Databricks:

```
local variable 'ret' referenced before assignment
```

The error points on --> `print(ret)` (see below).
**There shouldn't be any scope problem, since my `print ret` is out of my `if then else` statement.**

I tried to play with different indentations, but nothing works. Does anyone have a clue? (ps: I don't have access to the Python versions on DB since it's not my personal account, so I'm asking a solution to cope with the current environment I have)

Here is an extract of the code that work on Visual Studio Code but not on Databricks.
There is a lot of code but I just want to check with you the general **structure** I made a simplified model below.

```
        for FX_ext in ['', 'full_FX_', 'USD_FX_']: 
            for bt_type, field in trafo_dict.items():       
                MPs = val[field].values
                MPs_null = MPs.copy()
                MPs_null[0] = np.nan

            for period in ['1d', 'Nd']:
                #print(MPs_null[shifts[period]]) #########

                if FX_ext == '':
                    try:
                        ret = MPs_null[shifts[period]] / MPs[:-1]
                    except:
                        print()
                        pass

                elif FX_ext == 'USD_FX_':
                     usd = sp_list['FX_rates_USD']
                     ret = np.array(MPs_null[shifts[period]]).astype(float) * np.array(usd[shifts[period]]).astype(float) / \
                          np.array(np.array(MPs[:-1]).astype(float)*np.array(usd[:-1])).astype(float) ## Hallelujah :D
                else:
                    c= dict()
                    retlst = []
                    for curr in ['USD', 'EUR', 'GBP']:
                        c = sp_list[f'FX_rates_{curr}']
                        retlst.append(
                                np.array(MPs_null[shifts[period]]).astype(float) * np.array(c[shifts[period]]).astype(float) / \
                                np.array((np.array(MPs[:-1]).astype(float)*np.array(c[:-1]).astype(float))) )# Jesus christ finally succeded to resolve this issue
                    ret = functools.reduce(np.minimum, retlst)
                print(ret)
```

The whole is part of a bigger function and the same happens when I run it as a whole system.

I tried to test a similar and simplified structure on Databricks **to check if nothing was fundamentally wrong with my Databricks and Python versions and this worked** (no scope issue):

```
a = 5

for period in [1, 3]: 
    if a ==5:
      b = a + period
    elif a >5:
      b = 48
    else:
      b=0
    print(b)

Output:
6
8
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: There is one branch where `ret` doesn't get defined, if `FX_ext == ''` and the `try` fails. Could it be that you are in this case on Databricks?

Comment: That was the issue indeed. It's because Databricks environment needed"ret" to be defined on each branch as you say. Thank you four reply! You are saving my job! :)